# Hiveql aggregation :difference between two values

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm using hive coupled with hadoop.I'm lookinfor a function (hiveql) which permit to have difference between the last/first value of the day.The data has recorded every 5 minute (Gauge or Counter which increments) for each resource name and i want to have an aggregation having one value per day per resource name (mac).
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2yhW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions `first_value` and `last_value`:

```
    select colldate, 
           max(last_success - first_success) as success,
           max(last_conmiss - first_conmiss) as conmiss,
           resourcename
    from
    (
    select 
         first_value(success) over(partition by resourcename, colldate order by colltime) first_success,
         last_value(success) over(partition by resourcename, colldate order by colltime) last_success,
         first_value(conmiss) over(partition by resourcename, colldate order by colltime) first_conmiss,
         last_value(conmiss) over(partition by resourcename, colldate order by colltime) last_conmiss,
    colldate, resourcename
    from (select s.*, to_date(s.colltime) colldate from table s) s
    )s
group by colldate, resourcename;
```

See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics